# Creating a class that implements an interface within the interface itself

Tags: android, kotlin, oop

I was looking at this code on the MarsUI android tutorial by developers.android:

```
sealed interface MarsUiState {
    data class Success(val photos: List<MarsPhoto>) : MarsUiState
    object Error : MarsUiState
    object Loading : MarsUiState
}
```

It looks like the `Success` data class implements the same interface it is inside of. How is that possible? It feels like some recursive magic. Doesn't the class need the interface to exist first?

I'd expect that if I need the interface, I would create a class that implements it outside of it or pass a `::class.java` to some other function that would do the creation of that class.

Comment: Somebody is going to provide a better worded answer than I can, and I hope they use the correct terminology when they do. You should be very wary of the wording you are using. You care not *creating* nor *instantiating* an interface, you are *declaring it*. Once it has been declared the compiler can use it according to the language rules.

Comment: Thank you very much @MaartenBodewes! The editing has really helped me understand how to post on this platform. I also appreciate your insight on the keywords. I understand how useful it can be to use the correct words for more efficient communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is that possible?

The Kotlin compiler allows it.

> It feels like some recursive magic. Doesn't the class need the interface to exist first?

No. The processing of the classes happens at *compile* time. Nothing "exists" at *compile* time. The compiler is validating syntax and, when everything checks out, creates the bytecode that will actually run.

Your code is just text. You and I, by looking at the text, can tell that an interface name `MarsUiState` is being declared and that a class `Success` implements that interface that was just declared. The fact that `Success` is "inside" `MarsUiState` is just a semantic detail.

That is, the creators of the language have decided that this is valid syntax for defining a sealed class hierarchy. They could have decided that you you needed to annotate the class, declare it in a separate file, or prefixed the class name with "BooYah!". As long as it followed some logic the compiler could parse.

Don't confuse *declaring* the class inside the interface as *having* an instance of the class within the interface (*that* would be recursive).

Similarly, the Kotlin compiler has been coded to detect that `MarsUiState` has been declared by the time it parses `Success` and the creators of the language have decided that this is valid syntax.

Comment: thank you for your response! what do you mean by "just a semantic detail"? are you implying that, visibility unaffected, we can declare variables and classes anywhere?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the way you define a sealed class is just what the creators of the language settled on for how sealed classes worked. Updated the answer to clarify and expand.

Comment: No, only where it is allowed by the language specifications. It is a "semantic detail" because as far as the compiler is concerned, it found a declaration of the interface and it can then use that declaration *even if* the contents are not clear yet. Undoubtedly there are languages that do not allow this, but these are modern languages that are relatively permissive.  As for this particular one, I think it is covered by "A statement scope is DLD to any directly nested scope", see [section 6.1 of the Kotlin language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/scopes-and-identifiers.html#linked-scopes).

Comment: You're right @dominicoder. I looked at the documentation for it and it is literally the point of a sealed class. So I get why it is just semantics: even without the brackets, the code would behave the same. I wonder why they chose to put the implementing objects and class in the brackets. Is it just for readability? Behaviourally, the only difference I could see is that if the object and class were declared somewhere else far from the interface, there could be an issue of the compiler not recognizing the interface. However, like MaartenBodewes mentioned, it is not a problem

Comment: I look at it as a "grouping". Sealed classes form a closed hierarchy, a finite set. Wrapping the classes that extend a sealed class / interface within the definition of that class / interface reinforces that idea, just like a function uses braces to group its logic; a class uses braces to group its members, etc. But "why?" is a question only the language creators can answer.